# Unexpected Token ILLEGAL on running node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, token

I'm doing a programming course and I'm trying to run the command node server.js. However this is the result I get.

```
node server.js

/home/lalitp/webapp/imad-app/server.js:26
console.log(`IMAD course app listening on port ${port}!`);
        ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
at startup (node.js:119:16)
at node.js:902:3
```

This is the server.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var path = require('path');

var app = express();
app.use(morgan('combined'));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'ui', 'index.html'));
});

app.get('/ui/style.css', function (req, res) {
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'ui', 'style.css'));
});

app.get('/ui/madi.png', function (req, res) {
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'ui', 'madi.png'));
});


// Do not change port, otherwise your app won't run on IMAD servers
// Use 8080 only for local development if you already have apache running on 80

var port = 80;
app.listen(port, function () {
console.log(`IMAD course app listening on port ${port}!`);
});
```

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: The Node version that you're using is probably too old (find out the version with `node --version`). Since it looks like you're using Linux, and typically Linux distro's ship (very) old Node.js versions, look here for instructions on installing a more recent version: https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/

Comment: Thanks @robertklep looks like it solved the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably using an older version of Node.js, which does not support the so-called back-tick quoted strings (surrounded by the ` character).

If you change

```
console.log(`IMAD course app listening on port ${port}!`);
```

to

```
console.log('IMAD course app listening on port ' + port + '!');
```

it should work.

The back-tick quoted strings are for interpolating variables, i.e. integrating a JavaScript expression into a string. This makes long strings with lots of variables easier to read than concatenating every single bit by using the `+` operator.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're using ES5 and not ES6 so you cannot use **`** token for a string :

```
console.log('IMAD course app listening on port ${port}!');
```